# Winsock C TCP Socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, winsock

I've worked with TCP sockets before in Python. It looks pretty similar in C but I can't get anything to work. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` returns -1, which of course indicates an error. How could I go so wrong so fast?
If you could help me with this problem, that would be nice, but it would be incredibly helpful if you could provide me with some simple, bare bones source code. It doesn't need to even do anything really, and it doesn't need to handle errors. I just need to see how to properly create a server socket, bind it, listen on it, and accept clients and how to create and connect a client socket. I can figure out all the bells and whistles on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: what does `WSAGetLastError()` return after your socket call?

Comment: Does the user the program runs as have permission to use the network?

Comment: WSAGetLastError returns 10093, and I routinely run programs written in Python that use sockets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to initialise WinSock with the [`WSAStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function before you can use sockets. Python's implementation of sockets on Windows likely calls this automatically so you don't need to worry about it, however when using WinSock directly it is important to call `WSAStartup` before any other WinSock calls, and when your program is done with sockets, you need to call `WSACleanup`.

```
WSAData data;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data) != 0)
{
    // unable to initialise WinSock, time to quit
}

// WinSock has been successfully initialised, time to make sockets!
int s = socket(...);

// After all WinSock stuff is done, balance out your WSAStartup with a cleanup:
WSACleanup();
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use WSAStartup. This kind of C programming confuses me...

Answer (score 9):

Have you called [`WSAStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before making any other winsock calls?

Answer (score 3):

Client:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=VS.85).aspx

Server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's just that the process has no permission to create sockets (`errno == EACCES`).

Perhaps your python interpreter is getting a different security context, check that.

Anyway, better safe than sorry, so put there something like:

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock == -1) {
        perror("myapp");
        exit(1);
}
```

IDK if Winsock actually sets `errno`, but it should...

Comment: Winsock is not part of the CRT, so it wouldn't have access to `errno`.  It does, however, set an error code that can be retrieved with `WSAGetLastError`.

Comment: That's weird, `errno` should be locatable anyway... (but you can always expect something like that from Microsoft's softwares)

Comment: So is there some function to translate it into a human readable text string?

Comment: It's not a "Microsoft's software" thing -- it's a matter of the runtime and the OS being distinct.  `errno` isn't a system thing, it's a runtime library thing.  Non-RTL functions shouldn't really be touching it.  As for turning it into an error string, there's the [`FormatMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, it is a "Microsoft's software" thing, errno is a standard component of the c library, meant to report _any_ *system error*. And IPC errors are a system errors. They just implemented it wrong. Also, the term RTL doesn't make sense, why would you link a library you wouldn't use at run-time?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that anything coming from a syscall **must** be reported via errno.

Comment: "RTL" means the C runtime library -- the library that has all the standard functions and does all the support stuff necessary to run C code (parsing args, calling `main`, handling system-level errors, etc).  It uses `errno` for reporting *runtime* errors, not system errors.  The RTL's job is to present the program with an abstract machine that aligns with C's requirements.  The OS, however, doesn't care about the application or the runtime, and quite rightly doesn't rely on `errno` to even exist -- a program written in assembly language, for example, might not have an `errno`.

Comment: Oh, and last i saw, `read`, `write`, etc aren't even defined by the C standard.  They're POSIX-defined functions, and they're just in Windows mostly because they're so common everywhere else.  Those "syscalls" have no special meaning to C, and aren't actually syscalls -- they're just RTL wrappers around the actual syscalls, and take the result from the OS and set `errno` appropriately.

Comment: I'm just not comfortable the RTL concept because libraries aren't being generated at run-time. We could talk about run-time environment, instead, in reference to the specific instances of those libraries and their state.

Comment: Now, about errno, the C standard guarantees it. And it's used on almost all operating systems by the dynamic loader library, syscall wrappers, and POSIX API, independently if those are part of the standard C library or not.

Comment: Well, anyway, I always forget Microsoft doesn't care to support standards... 12 years and they still don't support C99...

Comment: "Runtime" doesn't refer so much to when the code runs...it refers to the "hosted environment" defined by the C standard (5.1.2).  And if you check out the specs for `errno`, it's for the library.  There's no requirement *whatsoever* that any function not defined in the standard touch `errno`.  In fact, (1) `errno` *need not be an actual variable* -- it could be a macro (7.5), so external programs compiled with some other compiler couldn't really know how to find it anyway.  (2) The C standard defines precisely *three* error-code macros (7.5 again), and any others are implementation-defined.

Comment: POSIX may make some guarantees over and above that, but Windows ain't POSIX. And for reference, GCC doesn't support all of C99 either. So quit the "MS doesn't care about standards" stuff; truth is, there's hardly a compiler out there that supports the whole thing.  And VC++ hasn't been a C compiler for some time; it's a C++ compiler that happens to be able to compile C code.

Comment: GCC implementation of C99 is fairly complete. Microsoft on the other hand doesn't even try.

Comment: `errno` is guaranteed to evaluate to a mutable type. As for why compilers would use different implementations of the C library, is mostly Microsoft fault by no providing a proper shared-library implementation everyone can use... of course, just another thing that doesn't makes any sense.

Comment: If you don't do it that way, things start to break... why then to bother "stealing" code from BSD anyway?

Comment: At least they could have provided wrappers in the headers to set `errno`... most compilers did inline code back then too...

Comment: `errno` is guaranteed to evaluate to a mutable lvalue *in C/C++, after preprocessing, **if `<errno.h>` is included** *.  DLLs can't rely on its name, location, or anything else, *including its very existence*.  (Windows programs don't have to be written in C, and non-C programs may not have any such variable -- most languages have a much more sensible way of handling errors anyway.)  Sure, you could have a library of wrappers around the functions in wsock2_32, and they might even exist...never cared to find out, really.  I have no interest in turning Windows into *nix.

Comment: Windows can't very easily have a single C library because it has never been like *nix.  In *nix, you generally have one compiler, provided by whoever provided the OS (and/or you have GCC), which also compiled the C library.  With that, you get a canonical C library and a pretty entrenched spec for libraries.  Windows has always been more fragmented than that, devwise, particularly since there's no One True Compiler for it.  Whose C library should we use?  What format?  MSVC's?  Why?

Comment: The case of non-C code isn't an excuse, it would be just part of the API.

Comment: OTOH, the standard C library is meant to be part of the OS, thus unique. Changing the library means it's a different platform.

Comment: The standard C library *does not care* about the OS.  It doesn't care whether it's part of the OS, and certainly doesn't expect to hold some special place within it.  POSIX might make such assumptions, but again, Windows ain't POSIX.

Comment: Oh, and a "last system error" *is* part of the API.  It's called `GetLastError()`.

Comment: The point is BSD designates `errno`, thus Microsoft implementation is broken. Also, I would like to clarify that the standard C library is the evolution of a subset of the original UNIX system libraries, thus it has a place as a system library. OTOH, I've seen many non-UNIX systems to provide conformant implementations (e.g. AmigaOS and BeOS).